# One that is paid but cannot be bought

Tags: riddle, wordplay, poetry

Two words are homophones

> One that is paid
>   $\quad$ but cannot be bought
>   The other is stated
>   $\quad$ but cannot be undone

What are the two words?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Last one I swear:

I think it's

> tolled/told

because

One is paid but can't be bought

> if you've been tolled, you paid a toll but cannot buy one

The other is stated, but can't be undone

> told is past-tense, so it can't be undone.

Comment: Spot on! You got it right!

Comment: whew, that was a tough one! Only took four answers lol (deleted one)

Answer (score 13):

I want to say

> **due** and **do**

Two words are homophones

> Yep, these sound the same

One that is paid

> People can "pay their dues", literally or figuratively

but cannot be bought

> Purchasing a due doesn't make sense

The other is stated

> `do` is a statement in some programming languages

but cannot be undone

> I'm thinking this is wordplay, and you can't un-do "do" because if you did, it would no longer be "do" at all

I know this goes in a strange direction at the end. For the last clue... either I figured out the trick part of the puzzle, or it's just plain wrong, and I'm honestly not sure which. The one before it came from the meta-knowledge that programming concepts seem to show up disproportionately often on this site.

Comment: I think more of weddings for the latter half of this

Comment: Nice try, the first clue fits perfectly well, but are due and do really homophones? Besides, *undo* is exactly what it means here :)

Comment: How would you pronounce "due" and "do" in a non-homophonic way?

Comment: Ah, answered my own question. I'm familiar with what seems to be the standard US pronunciation, IPA /du/, whereas you are possibly more familiar with IPA /dʒuː/ (more of a j-like sound at the start) for "due". That one seems more standard in the Commonwealth.

Answer (score 9):

> **Compliment and complement**
>
>  [**Compliment**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compliment) - a remark that expresses approval, admiration, or respect. You can pay someone a compliment but it can't be bought.
>
>  [**Complement**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/complement) -  to make something else seem better or more attractive when combining with it. You can state that one thing is the complement of another and the two things are often intrinsically linked

Comment: Nice attempt, but not close :) Not all clauses were addressed.

Comment: Seems like the whole thing fits just compliment, except it being homophones(2) of course

Comment: @TCooper that's what I thought at first!

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer is

> Cheque/Check

One that is paid
 but cannot be bought

> You can pay a cheque into your bank account but you cannot buy a cheque.

The other is stated
 but cannot be undone

> In chess, you state "Check!" when the king is under attack and once this is done, it is against the rules to take the move back.

Comment: The second one holds pretty well! But you *can* technically buy a cheque-book from a bank provided you have an account in it.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Technically yes, but they usually just give them to you. I have three I've never used. I mean, technically, you can buy almost anything.

Comment: But not the one mentioned in the question, I’m afraid ;)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Ok, will have a rethink

Comment: I have a good feeling you could nail this one, @hexomino, Good luck!

Comment: You can buy a cashier's check, which means the money is guaranteed to be available for the check. There's often a fee for this. Same goes for a traveler's check. And you can take back a "check" in chess, if you realize it's not actually "check".

Answer (score 4):

I think it's

> principle / principal

because

One that is paid, but cannot be bought

> principal on your loan is paid, but you can't buy said principal. Similarly the principal of a school is paid, and as a person, cannot be bought

The other is stated, but cannot be changed

> a principle is a basic truth or law, we state them, but cannot change them. i.e. gravity

Answer (score 3):

It could be

> Witcher/Whicher

because

One that is paid
but cannot be bought

> A Witcher requires payment, but will turn down any job he doesn't want, no matter the price offered.

The other is stated
but cannot be undone

> more of a stretch here, but `The Suspicions of Mr. Whicher` are stated, and after accusing someone, it can't be undone!

Side note:

> Have a feeling I stretched too far, but thought it was a fun answer nonetheless

Comment: I like this answer, I'll toss a coin your way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a longshot.

> attention
>  1. You can pay attention, but it can't be bought
>  2. You can be in a state of tension (state o' tension), and stress could have a permanent effect on a person

I have my doubts about the last condition.

Answer (score 2):

This might be

> Ad(advertisement)/Add

One that is paid
but cannot be bought

> Paid advertisement is any kind of advertising that you have to pay for it, can't be bought.

The other is stated
but cannot be undone

> Add - join something to increase the size or number